# Window does not get focus after expand it from tray while holding tab WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

When you have an application hiding in the tray, you should be able to expand it. Here the problem comes in: when I holding tab key to switch focus in taskbar and try to show the window with `hWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)` and `SetForegroundWindow(*hWnd)` calls, my window is not activated. I have the ability to work with it, but it doesn't have focus for the tab key until I click it again (in the tray) without holding the tab.
The problem is that when I call ShowWindow and SetForegroundWindow I get 0 return code from both.
Sample code:

```
// blablabla working with messages loop
void OnShowTrayWindow(UINT /*message*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/) {
// handle some situations
    m_hWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW); // returns 0 in my case
    SetForegroundWindow(*m_hWnd); // returns 0 in my case
    SetFocus(m_hWnd);
}
```

My window have WS_TABSTOP flag in styles. Actually, tab works perfectly when I have activated window.

P.S. I think that this behavior can be related with the SetForegroundWindow requirements (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow)

Comment: Yes it does.  You just answered your own question in the edit.

Comment: Is there is hacks to solve it?

Comment: Don't think so.  The behaviour is by design, the thinking being that it's the user who should decide what the foreground window is at any particular moment, not some random application.  That said, it sounds like what you're trying to do is fine, might be worth submitting feedback to MS.

Comment: @PaulSanders is it possible to switch focus from taskbar to new window?

Comment: IDK, sorry, but I don't think the taskbar is particularly special in this regard.  If the code you've posted doesn't do it then probably nothing will.

Comment: As I know so far, most of current application have the same problem, but some Windows' apps somehow avoid it.

Comment: Ever since Windows switched to its new UI platform (sorry, it doesn't have a name, that's why you don't find many complaints about it), keyboard support just imploded. It took years for WinUI2 (its successor) to even provide basic keyboard handling. To this day the keyboard interface sucks for anything using WinUI2/3.

Comment: @IInspectable _it doesn't have a name, that's why you don't find many complaints about it_ LMAO

Comment: @ShamilMukhetdinov By that, do you mean some _Microsoft_ apps?  Well, they can do what the hell they like, clearly, because they are inside the guardrail.

Comment: @PaulSanders, yeap, some Microsoft apps have some trick. I thought that we could reproduce that.

Comment: Sadly, Microsoft keep a lot of tricks to themselves.